# Optimisation of sampling without replacement

Tags: r, optimization, sampling

Is there any way to make this considerably faster?

`out1 <- sapply(1:1e6, function(ii) sample.int(10, 10, replace = FALSE) )`

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you would also be happy with a list, `lapply()` is faster, because `sapply()` uses it internally and simplifies the list to an arrray. Or look into parallelization, `parallel::par*apply`.

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck here is the repeated call to `sample.int`, and unless you can get rid of it, I doubt the call will be much faster. Would you ever need to sample from larger vectors (i.e. with more than 10 elements)? Because if not, you could precompute all the permutions and then sample from them. For 10 elements, there are only 3628800 permutations.

```
x <- sapply(1:1e6, function(ii) sample.int(10, 10, replace = FALSE) )
```

A version without `sapply`.

```
rand_x <- function(samples = 1e6, size = 10) {
    ans <- numeric(samples*size)
    dim(ans) <- c(size, samples)

    for (i in seq_len(samples))
        ans[, i] <- sample.int(size)
    ans
}
```

Precomputing combinations.

```
library("combinat")
C <- permn(1:10)
C <- do.call(cbind, C)
## int [1:10, 1:3628800] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

rand_x2 <- function(samples = 1e6, C) {
    p <- sample.int(ncol(C), samples, replace = TRUE)
    C[, p]
}
```

Comparing speeds.

```
library("rbenchmark")
benchmark(sapply(1:1e6, function(ii) sample.int(10, 10, replace = FALSE) ),
          rand_x(),
          rand_x2(C = C),
          replications = 5, order = "relative")

##                   test replications elapsed relative user.self
## 3       rand_x2(C = C)            5   0.633    1.000     0.634
## 2             rand_x()            5  14.352   22.673    14.351
## 1 sapply(1:1e+06, ...)            5  18.435   29.123    18.422
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking the time to come up with a nice solution. Unfortunately, as you probably figured, this is the bottle neck in a much larger routine. So, although the function itself (rand_x2) is extremely fast, the cost is having to execute 'permn(1:10)' which makes the whole thing slower than the original on my machine. And, yes, as you correctly guessed, I the vector size is not fixed but variable and likely to be up to 15 or so the number of permutations is going to be unmanageable!